# module for Ubercart to run a discount per product in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, shopping-cart, ubercart

Hey guys I'm **looking for a module and combination of modules** to let me **add items to Ubercart with discounts**. How did you apply them?

These items **need to have their own discounts** that are **not applied to the entire cart**, just that product. They should also not require user input to get.

The discount will be **based on the quantity of the product added**. That is for example:

- at 1-10 items, a 5% discount
- at 11-25 items, a 25% discount
- and so one

So, I can have **two or more products all having different discounts** based on the number of each. For example:

- 3 apples 15% discount
- 1000 nuts 50% discount

I have tried a few options and had no luck, including http://drupal.org/project/uc_discounts_alt, however it is not **working with Drupal 6.2**.

Also, **I'm ok with having to write php** to get this to work so if there is something that will let me do that then awesome.

**P.S.** I'm new to Ubercart but I do not think this is a built in feature

Comment: I don't know why you say uc_discounts_alt does not work with Drupal 6.2, but this is the right module for you. It is VERY modular and can do all what you asked for. In addition, in case it does not gives exactly what you want - you should use this module as the basis for development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [uc_coupon module](http://drupal.org/project/uc_coupon) ? I think it's going to help you a lot. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue once.

The first time I did it, I utilized uc_get_cart_contents, hard coded my discount conditions, and adjusted the price accordingly. Works, but, doesn't scale.

The second time, I used uc_coupon module. Saved time.

Comment: how did you apply this concept? I see the option to do bulk discounts and not simply product based. also, will users need to supply a "code"

Comment: I knew ahead of time what the conditions were, like buy shirt X and Y, total is 10% off. It was easy to write, but in no way flexible.